# adding a spinner inside a jtable cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable

so I'm trying to add a Jspinner inside a Jtable cell.

and I was initially doing something like the following inside the DefaultTableModel

```
  public Class<?> getColumnClass(int colNum) {
               if(colNum ==2)
                   return JSpinner.class
        return String.class;

 }
```

However, after doing this I get the following:

[image]

I tried to search for the error message but it wasn't helpful at all.

I'm assuming that return JSpinner.class approach can't actually work. If that's the case, then can anyone suggest any other approach?

Comment: @ReşitDönük I'm trying to display the spinner

Answer (score 2):

No, do not keep components inside a model, a model holds data, use a `CellRenderer` and `CellEditor` to determine how that data is shown and edited by the user

See

- [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)
- [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)
- [Using Other Editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor)

for more details